I94 record not updated after departure of B2 visitor from the US
Checking the I94 record online for this B2 visitor (family member) that was visiting me here in the USA for about 2 months.
She left August 27th, 3 pm and today (August 31st), the I94 record still shows no update indicating her departure.
Do I have to do anything to indicate departure? I thought CBP automatically receives departure info from the airlines and doesn't stamp exit in passport anymore?
Questions:

should I expect her I94 online record to update indicating departure?
how long can this take? a week, a few days, a month?
if doesn't update, will this become a cause for concern for her entry next time into the USA?
should I be contacting the CBP to get this updated? If yes, how long should I wait before I contact them? Is there any other way?
Does she need to save her boarding pass of flight departing the USA? She also has an entry stamp in her passport from when she entered her home country. CBP didn't put an exit stamp in there though.


It can take weeks, from my experience

CBP hasn't inspected departing passengers for at least 50 years.  "Do I have to do anything to indicate departure?": Are you asking on her behalf or because you're worried that you might get in trouble if CBP thinks that she overstayed?

I think you're worrying a bit prematurely. While if after a week or two it's not updated there may be cause for slight worry, at this time it's probably just going through the wheels and cogs.

CBP didn't put an exit stamp in [her passport]

That's quite normal given she didn't see anyone from CBP on her way out: there are no exit checks in the US.
Her boarding pass + the stamp in the destination country should be enough proof if there are any issues, make sure she holds onto those if they are ever needed. Wait for a 2 or 3 weeks and if her I-94 hasn't updated, you can contact CBP to have it fixed, though that shouldn't even be necessary, but is probably a good idea to avoid any delays next time.
Does she have a single passport? Are there any mismatches in name(s), birth date or other details between the passport she used for entry, her B-2 visa, and the data provided to the airline when she departed? That could explain longer than usual processing times.

thanks. As a follow-up to future visitors here, it was recently updated to show her departure date. Almost 3-4 weeks after her departure from the US.
